# Physics and unit size to feet

Tags: physics, directx, kinematic

I'm dropping a object 1353 feet from a building. I can get the time(t) it lands with manipulating the total displacement of a object(/\x).

[image]

---

[image]

Gravity is 32 feet/s^2

While doing physics, kinematics or projectiles like above do not return the right results. I cannot rely on the physics which is the real world result in a game. One unit equals how many feet in DirectX? How do you put physics of the real world into a game? How can I convert 1353 feet to how many units...

Answer (score 1):

A unit in DirectX is whatever you want it to be. Meters, feet, microns, screen-pixels, light-years... whatever makes sense in the context of the scene you are rendering. Just make sure you scale any assets you import so that they are the correct scale for your preferred unit-length.

If you then add real-world physics, you have to make sure that you also use the same unit of length in your physics systems. So when you decide that one unit is one foot, then you have to take earth gravity not as 9.81 (m/s²) but as 32.17 (feet/s²). So you seem to have that part correct.

But calculating gravity in a vacuum is relatively simple. What's not so simple to simulate are the aerodynamic forces affecting an object falling through an atmosphere. There are just too many variables which affect the trajectory of flying things in the real world. Any formulas you find are usually just approximations which quickly fall apart in certain edge-cases we observe in reality. For example, consider cases where aerodynamic forces outweigh gravitational forces. Like a leaf getting blown off a tree by an autumn storm. Or a paper airplane. What makes these objects even harder to predict is that they are flexible. Aerodynamic forces affect their shape, which in turn affects their aerodynamic properties. So you have a chaotic system. Good luck predicting those with just a simple formula.

So when you got measurements of falling objects taken in the real-world and want to  replicate them as accurately as possible in a virtual environment, then you have quite a challenge ahead of you. You have to create a full-fledged simulation of air-flows, which is [a very specialized field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics). And even the most accurate simulation models (those which are far too slow to calculate in real-time) *still* include a couple inaccuracies which results in slight differences between simulated results and experimental results.

And it's rarely useful for games to go into such detail. Even games like *Kerbal Space Program*, which try to model physics accurately, take a lot of shortcuts and simplifications when it comes to aerodynamics. Which lead to results which are not 100% realistic, but easier to program, quicker to calculate and most importantly easier to understand for the player.